# How can I link The Ring Two (2005) and Rings (2017)?

Tags: plot-explanation, continuity, rings, the-ring-two

At the end of *The Ring Two* (2005), Rachel closes the lid of the well, sealing Samara inside.
What was the point of doing this? 
In Rings (2017), Samara still roams free in the tapes.

What changed after Rachel closed the well to trap Samara therein?

Comment: Maybe she dug a tunnel. xD

Comment: @LeonX or simply, she reopned it using her hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What was the point of Rachel closing the lid of the well?**

It was for reversing the mistake Rachel did in *The Ring*. She is the one who opened the lid. She just took what she did in first film back, Samara is still able to do what she did in *The Ring*.

**What changed after Rachel closed the well to trap Samara therein?**

She was able to save Aidan from Samara. Now she is not as free as she was in the beginning of *The Ring Two*. She is back to square one.

<sub>Note: I have not seen *Rings* yet but it's based on my extrapolation of *The Ring* and *The Ring Two*.</sub>